# Different Invoice/Order Emails for same Transactional Email template

Tags: invoice, email-templates, transactional

I created a custom Transactional Email for Order and Invoice. To list the items that were ordered I use this call `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

I customized it while making test purchases from my main store view. Now I found out, that if I purchase something from my mobile store view, the transactional email for order and ivoice look different (s. picture)

[image]

web looks alright, but when the purchase was done via the mobile website, the table format doesn't fit. I already looked into folder structure. For the web store view all the template files were in "email" folders like `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\bundle\email`.

Where do I find the files to change the table for mobile store view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The iphone files for `tax.phtml` and `totals.phtml` where missing the

`<?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>`call in `<td>` tag.

Now the emails look the same, no matter from which device the user makes a purchase.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *nix put this in your console:

> find . | xargs grep 'sales_email_order_items' -sl

That command inside the app/design/frontend/ will give you the name of the XML dealing with that layout handle and inside there you will see the PHTMLS and Blocks being used to show the email you need to modify.

I got:

```
michael@michael-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:/var/www/magento/app/design/frontend$ find . | xargs grep 'sales_email_order_items' -sl
./rwd/default/layout/sales.xml
./rwd/default/layout/bundle.xml
./rwd/default/layout/downloadable.xml
./base/default/layout/sales.xml
./base/default/layout/bundle.xml
./base/default/layout/downloadable.xml
./default/iphone/layout/sales.xml
./default/iphone/layout/bundle.xml
./default/modern/layout/sales.xml
```

so the question is now which theme are you using.

Comment: for mobile I use the iphone theme, for web I use default/blank. In the iphone sales.xml, for example, there is the entry `<block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">` But as I mentioned before, there is no folder email anywhere inside the magento project, with an iphone path

Comment: You will have to do some tests to see how to make them work in mobile, but i think this is the answer you were looking for.